# Как перевести число в цвет

Tags: python, парсер

Я делаю парсер `.vox` файлов
У меня есть поле `palette`
И в нём находятся числа:

```py
[853769,2230549,3999000,11343896,14241548,16750606,16775513,14087784,9435703,1482278,1858858,866338,859423,6431,12600,25687,36205,574623,5889968,11200714,4572633,2463183,154009,1653393,1053752,593177,1381688,3024461,5647987,10500766,13133199,15577017,16238809,16249806,15852719,15191187,13737585,10382671,7549486,5056048,2365216,1839638,1052946,2105891,5792098,11120816,13817559,15856369]
```

Как мне перевести эти числа в нормальный цвет (RGB)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наверное, переводом в 16-ричный вид:

```py
data = [853769,2230549,3999000,11343896,14241548,16750606,16775513,14087784,9435703,1482278,1858858,866338,859423,6431,12600,25687,36205,574623,5889968,11200714,4572633,2463183,154009,1653393,1053752,593177,1381688,3024461,5647987,10500766,13133199,15577017,16238809,16249806,15852719,15191187,13737585,10382671,7549486,5056048,2365216,1839638,1052946,2105891,5792098,11120816,13817559,15856369]
for x in data:
    print(f'{x:06X}')
```

Вывод:

```
0D0709
220915
3D0518
AD1818
D94F0C
FF980E
FFF959
D6F668
8FFA37
169E26
1C5D2A
0D3822
0D1D1F
00191F
003138
006457
008D6D
08C49F
59DFB0
AAE8CA
45C5D9
2595CF
025999
193A91
101438
090D19
151538
2E264D
562E73
A03A9E
C8658F
EDAFB9
F7C8D9
F7F3CE
F1E4AF
E7CC93
D19E71
9E6D4F
73322E
4D2630
241720
1C1216
101112
202223
586162
A9B0B0
D2D6D7
F1F2F1
```

Comment: ООО работает, спасибо